# After which event does the preload script start running (Electron)

Tags: electron

I couldn't find any detailed resource about the preload script.
I don't understand after which event (did-finish-load/did-start-load/will-navigate/did-navigate ....) does the preload script begin to run.

I tried searching for detailed preload explanation but all I could find were minimal documents that explain only the minimum.

I would appreciate such a document as well.

Answer (score 0):

electron-quick-start

```
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
```

According the Electron Quick Start Guide, preload.js is

```
preload.js - A content script that runs before the renderer process loads.
```

But depending on what you wish to accomplish within your preload.js script, for example accessing the DOM of the your html page, you will have to wait till your page has loaded...

Example:

```
// When document has loaded, initialize
document.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        // Do something useful here...
    }
};
```